# Print in python shell when using multiprocessing.Process()

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I made the following script which is almost the same as available [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import sys

def f(n):
    print n
#    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f('hello')
    p = Process(target = f, args=('python',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'bye'
```

When i run the script in python IDLE, it outputs :

```
hello
bye
```

and not :

```
hello 
python
bye
```

But when i run the script in windows terminal it gives the required output. Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925399/python-enthought-canopy-multiprocessing-not-working), i tried `sys.stdout.flush()` as I thought there would be some buffering issues.

**How can I get the desired output in the python shell ?** Any suggestion is appreciated. I am using Python 2.7.9 [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.

EDIT:
I went through the question suggested in the comment. I ran the command `python -m idlelib.idle` as suggested from the terminal but it opened a python console and a shell. I ran my script through this shell but still the output was shown on the console and not the shell. 
How can I get the output on the shell directly so that i don't have to run the script from terminal every time when i have to debug using print statement ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can multiprocessing Process class be run from IDLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293178/can-multiprocessing-process-class-be-run-from-idle)

Comment: @ppasler i went through the link. I tried it. The output comes on the python console and not the shell. I want the shell to directly print the content.